# Unexpected increase in validation error in MNIST Pytorch

Tags: python, deep-learning, pytorch, mnist

I'm a bit new to the whole field and thus decided to work on the MNIST dataset. I pretty much adapted the whole code from https://github.com/pytorch/examples/blob/master/mnist/main.py, with only one significant change: Data Loading. I didn't want to use the pre-loaded dataset within Torchvision. So I used [MNIST in CSV](https://pjreddie.com/projects/mnist-in-csv/).

I loaded the data from CSV file by inheriting from Dataset and making a new dataloader.
Here's the relevant code:

```
mean = 33.318421449829934
sd = 78.56749081851163
# mean = 0.1307
# sd = 0.3081
import numpy as np
from torch.utils.data import Dataset, DataLoader

class dataset(Dataset):
    def __init__(self, csv, transform=None):
        data = pd.read_csv(csv, header=None)
        self.X = np.array(data.iloc[:, 1:]).reshape(-1, 28, 28, 1).astype('float32')
        self.Y = np.array(data.iloc[:, 0])

        del data
        self.transform = transform

    def __len__(self):
        return len(self.X)

    def __getitem__(self, idx):
        item = self.X[idx]
        label = self.Y[idx]

        if self.transform:
            item = self.transform(item)

        return (item, label)

import torchvision.transforms as transforms
trainData = dataset('mnist_train.csv', transform=transforms.Compose([
    transforms.ToTensor(),
    transforms.Normalize((mean,), (sd,))
]))
testData = dataset('mnist_test.csv', transform=transforms.Compose([
    transforms.ToTensor(),
    transforms.Normalize((mean,), (sd,))
]))

train_loader = DataLoader(dataset=trainData,
                         batch_size=10, 
                         shuffle=True,
                         )
test_loader = DataLoader(dataset=testData, 
                        batch_size=10, 
                        shuffle=True,
                        )
```

However this code gives me the absolutely weird training error graph that you see in the picture, and a final validation error of 11% because it classifies everything as a '7'.
[image: Validation error graph]

I managed to track the problem down to how I normalize the data and if I use the values given in the example code (0.1307, and 0.3081) for transforms.Normalize, along with reading the data as type 'uint8' it works perfectly.
Note that there is very **minimal difference in the data** which is provided in these two cases. Normalizing by 0.1307 and 0.3081 on values from 0 to 1 has the same effect as normalizing by 33.31 and 78.56 on values from 0 to 255. The values are even mostly the same (A black pixel corresponds to -0.4241 in the first case and -0.4242 in the second).

If you would like to see a IPython Notebook where this problem is seen clearly, please check out https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1W1qx7IADpnn5e5w97IcxVvmZAaMK9vL3

I am unable to understand what has caused such a huge difference in behaviour within these two slightly different ways of loading data. Any help would be massively appreciated.

Comment: 0.1307 and 0.3081 are the mean and standard deviation calculated on the MNIST dataset. In normalization, you usually use the mean and std of the dataset. I don't think you could use any set of values for that.

Comment: I have calculated the mean and standard deviation with respect to pixel intensities and those correspond to 33.31 and 78.56, when you look at it on a scale of 0 to 255

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Long story short: you need to change `item = self.X[idx]` to `item = self.X[idx].copy()`.

Long story long: `T.ToTensor()` runs [`torch.from_numpy`](https://github.com/pytorch/vision/blob/2d493d6a945cfaab8e72f0aa4be57db7264c64e0/torchvision/transforms/functional.py#L54), which returns a tensor which aliases the memory of your numpy array `dataset.X`. And `T.Normalize()` [works inplace](https://github.com/pytorch/vision/blob/2d493d6a945cfaab8e72f0aa4be57db7264c64e0/torchvision/transforms/functional.py#L194), so each time the sample is drawn it has `mean` subtracted and is divided by `std`, leading to degradation of your dataset.

Edit: regarding why it works in the original MNIST loader, the rabbit hole is even deeper. The key line in `MNIST` is that the image is [transformed](https://github.com/pytorch/vision/blob/7e973b8ad6e8ca220b3002ca4a5d284a82c1bfbe/torchvision/datasets/mnist.py#L71) into a [PIL.Image](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/3.1.x/reference/Image.html#PIL.Image.fromarray) instance. The operation claims to only copy in case the buffer is not contiguous (it is in our case), but under the [hood](https://github.com/python-pillow/Pillow/blob/ad26f53bf6494de24d64bb88ad651dfc8e41bd70/src/PIL/Image.py#L2518) it checks whether it's strided instead (which it is), and thus copies it. So by luck, the default torchvision pipeline involves a copy and thus in-place operation of `T.Normalize()` does not corrupt the in-memory `self.data` of our `MNIST` instance.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand that explanation - if you subtract the mean and divide by standard deviation after already doing that, it should have no effect, no? (Since the mean will be zero and the standard deviation will be 1)

Comment: That would be the case if you were calculating the mean and std each time (for each image). But this value is hard coded at the beginning of the script (presumably to the global mean and variance across the MNIST dataset), so everytime its subtraction of 33.318... and division by 78.56749... `T.Normalize(mean, std)` works with pre-calculated `mean` and `std` and is not dynamic

Comment: If I understand this correctly. in both cases there was degradation of the dataset, but because the values were larger in the first case (33 and 78 vs 0.13 and 0.30) there was higher degradation and the values started to diverge.

Comment: @nobody_nowhere no, the original implementation involves copying the samples and as such the in-place `torchivision.transform` operations do not corrupt the original. See my updated response for more in-depth explanation. I'm about to open an issue with `torchvision` regarding this behavior.

Comment: @Jatentaki To clarify, I meant the difference between the two cases in the IPython notebook. One where I load the values as type 'float32'(results in values Black 0 - White 255), divide the values by the std and mean of the dataset (33 and 78), and the other where I load the values as type 'uint8'(results in values Black 0 - White 1) and divide the values by the std and mean in this representation(0.13 and 0.30).

Comment: @Jatentaki The ultimate cause of the difference between these two cases is what I was referring to, which is due to the in-place behaviour of T.ToTensor() which degrades one more than the other because the magnitude of case 1 is higher

Comment: I see, I must admit I didn't look into the notebooks, I was referring to the difference of your implementation of the dataloader and the pytorch-provided one. Anyway, does that solve your problem?

Comment: Yeah. Using .copy() prevents the degradation of the data. Thank you