# Fully convolutional neural net in PyTorch will minimize loss but all predictions are the same?

Tags: conv-neural-network, pytorch

*Edit: The issue was a careless error on my part and not incorrect structure. Or rather, the structure WAS incorrect, but only because of a typo of sorts. I used ReLU activation on each layer before the output layer, but I also did ReLU separately on the input to the pooling layers. So I was doing ReLU twice each time. I'm still having issues with the model but at the very least I get varying output.*

I'm putting together a fully convolutional neural network in PyTorch and I'm having a bit of trouble getting results after the model has been trained. Now, the training portion is not nearly perfect, but for now it will minimize loss significantly, to the point where my results should look like something at least. However, when I make test predictions on the training data, the result is the same for every sample.

To give a bit of background on the purpose and structure, the input data are images and the result should be a single value (regression). As mentioned, it is fully convolutional and the structure is Conv/ReLU>pooling 3 times and then the last layer is just 1x1x1 conv with no activation. The loss function is Mean Squared Error, and I am using SGD as the optimizer.

My code is a bit lengthy, a bit ugly, and I'm not sure what specific portion is causing the error. Thus, for now I will refrain from posting any here, but if someone has a hunch as to the general culprit I can post any requested portion.

I'm simply hoping that this is an issue that would give a more experienced person a quick idea of what overall structure has been set up incorrectly. To me it seems like it is most likely the network itself, because as I said it appears to train just fine, but no matter the input image, the output is always the same single floating point number. Perhaps it is the activation functions (or lack thereof on the last layer)? Or maybe it actually is the training step and I'm doing something to mess up the end result? I should note that it looks like the weight value for that very last layer is the value of every prediction.

The input is normalized (i.e. subtracted mean and divide by stddev for each image), while the targets just have subtracted mean and are in the scale -1 to 1 (the original was 0 to 1).

Comment: @dedObed Well the behavior isn't constant overall, but since I randomize batches on each run they wouldn't be. Meaning, each time I train the model and make predictions, the actual value is different, but each prediction shares that same value in a given run.

Comment: Ah, sorry, now I see it.

Comment: Could [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53652015/unexpected-increase-in-validation-error-in-mnist-pytorch/53696375?noredirect=1#comment94363641_53696375) be an issue?

Comment: @Jatentaki Unfortunately no, as I do the normalization before I do anything with PyTorch at all. I process the data, then load it into a file and pull it down for training/eval. Also, that example seems to reference normalization using static parameters for the entire dataset, whereas I normalize each image. I did figure out the issue, and unfortunately it was just carelessness on my part. I'll be updating my question to discuss what it was.

Comment: are you initializing layers in forward instead of __init__? That could do this. I think you really should post your module structure here for anyone to help you. If the loss is well below 1, then it would be improbably for any single prediction to have low MSE, (assuming somewhat normal distribution on your labels), so something else must be going on. Although, that is a common downfall of MSE.

Comment: @modesitt No, layers were initialized in init, the error was actually that I was using ReLU twice in a row on each layer, I've updated the post. I'm leaving it up so a) people can see what my fix was and b) so people can see the suggestions of others just in case someone ends up having a similar issue where my fix isn't the solution.